# Editing using DexExpress PivotGrid

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

I have a WinForm with a PivotGridControl bound to a DataTable.  The DataTable is populated with a TableAdapter that knows how to update the underlying database table.

There is one field on the datatable that I want to allow the user to update.  This field will always appear in the body of the pivotGrid.

I have figured out how to associate an editor with the field.  When the user clicks on the cell, the editor appears, the user edits the value, and hits Enter, but this is where I run into trouble.

I cannot figure out which event on the grid (there does not appear to be a gridView) should be used as the PivotGrid equivalent of GridView's RowUpdated event.  Without this event, I am struggling to figure out where to put the ta.Update(myTable) statement.

Could someone recommend a technique for updating a database table through a pivotGrid?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EditValueChangedEvent.

> The EditValueChanged event is raised after an end-user has modified a
>   cell value and closed the editor. Handle the EditValueChanged event to
>   save changes made by an end-user to a data source.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_EditValueChangedtopic

Comment: Thanks - I think this will work for me, but I'm surprised there is nothing at the row level - that would be fired when the user is finished editing the row.

Comment: I dont think there are row's in a pivotgrid.